# No se cargan los css para movil con bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap

Estoy desarrollando este sitio: - y por algun motivo el css de movil no se está cargando ni el tablet ni el movil, no lo entiendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta añadir esto a tu header

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" >
```

me pasaba lo mismo con github pages y esa fue la solucion

Comment: Gracias, ese es el detalle que faltaba.